# How do I gain reputation so I can participate more?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

How do I gain reputation, I only have one, and to make more you need to vote on people's answers, but I only have 1 reputation and I need 15 to do so, and to answer some ones question, but you need 50 reputation?

Comment: Go to help->tour. You'll find a link to the rep privileges. You may always ask and answer, making your questions and answers available for upvoting. You need 50 to comment.

Comment: (1) Read the documentation a little more closely. You don’t get reputation *by voting on **other people’s answers***, you get reputation *by having other people vote **on your posts (questions and answers)***. You need to write some good questions and/or answers.  (2) You don’t need to have any reputation to write posts. You need 15 rep to vote for other people’s posts, and you should certainly do that when you earn that privilege, but there’s no rush. You need 50 rep to *write comments*, which is different from answering. There’s really no hurry to do that; it doesn’t get you any rep, anyway.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Just a note that votes on Meta don't affect rep, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting

Comment: [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: **SCROLL DOWN**. (Sorry for shouting, but I want to make sure new users who aren't used to the system see this.) This right here is a comment, which requires points to write but doesn't earn points. If you scroll down, you'll see the actual *Answers*, which you can usually post without any points and which will get you points if people up-vote them (on the main site; Meta is different).

Answer (score 11):

That's not quite how reputation works. Voting for other people's answers (and questions) gives those people reputation (except on meta). Also, nobody gets reputation from comments, even when they are upvoted.

To make this more clear, I've quoted ["What's Reputation"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), with some minor changes for clarification:

> Your reputation is increased when:
>
> - [your] question is voted up: +10
> - [your] answer is voted up: +10
> - [your] answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - [your] suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - [someone else's] bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Comment: So in order to gain reputation, you need to write answers or questions which other people think are good enough to vote on.